# How to check if Build failed in Finally

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I've got a BuildDefinition file, in the Finally part I deploy the application (B in image) using a console app due to the complexity of the deploy.

But when the build fails the application shouldn't be deployed.

So I thought use BuildDetail.Status (used in A) but the build isn't done yet it shows InProgress.

The question is, how do I stop the deployment from starting when the build fails? (possibly in the If (B).

[image: Part of builddefinition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out, should've used `BuildDetail.CompilationStatus`